# Recursively unzipping a folder with ZipFile/Python

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to write a script which can unzip something like this:

- Great grandfather.zip

  - Grandfather.zip

    - Father.zip

      - Child.txt

What I have so far:

```
from os import listdir
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile, is_zipfile

#Current Directory  
mypath = '.'


def extractor(path):
    for file in listdir(path):
        if(is_zipfile(file)):
            print(file)
            with ZipFile(file,'r') as zipObj:
                path = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
                zipObj.extractall(path)
                extractor(path)

extractor(mypath)
```

I can unzip great grandfather and when I call the extractor again with grandfather as path. It doesn't go inside the if statement. Even though, I can list the contents of grandfather.

Comment: So ?  What does that code do?  Errors, does not unzip something, ...?  You need to show your debugging process so we can help with either syntax or logic.  Read [ask] and  [mcve].

Comment: Replace `extractor(path)` by these two lines: **1** `os.chdir(path)` **2** `extractor('.')`.

Comment: Nice!  I put it as an answer, please accept it (check mark on on the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `extractor(path)` by these two lines:

- `os.chdir(path)`
- `extractor('.')`

So your code becomes:

```
from os import listdir
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile, is_zipfile

#Current Directory  
mypath = '.'


def extractor(path):
    for file in listdir(path):
        if(is_zipfile(file)):
            print(file)
            with ZipFile(file,'r') as zipObj:
                path = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
                zipObj.extractall(path)
                os.chdir(path)
                extractor('.')

extractor(mypath)
```